# Angular web app can't properly connect to my Spring Boot app API

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

This is what my console says upon running my Angular app (localhost:4200) –

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8090/api/orders' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED :8090/api/orders:1
ERROR HttpErrorResponse core.js:6210 
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:6210
```

This is my API service in Angular Web app –

```
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  baseAPI = 'http://localhost:8090/api/';
  orderId: number;
  orderAdd = {} as Order;

  getOrderList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseAPI + 'orders');
  }
  
}
```

Here's my controller class in Spring Boot app API –

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200/")
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class OrderAndBillingController {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepo;
    @Autowired
    private CafeClerk clerk;

    public OrderAndBillingController(CafeClerk clerk) {
        this.clerk = clerk;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/orders", produces = "application/json")
    public List<Order> getOrderList(){
        List<Order> list = new ArrayList<Order>();
        orderRepo.findAll().forEach(al -> list.add(al));
        return list;
    }
    @PostMapping(path = "/add", produces = "application/json")
    public void addOrder(@RequestBody Order order){
        orderRepo.save(order);
    }
    @PutMapping(path = "/update", produces = "application/json")
    public void updateOrder(@RequestBody Order order){
        orderRepo.save(order);
    }
    @DeleteMapping(path = "/delete/{id}", produces = "application/json")
    public void deleteOrder(@PathVariable("id") Order order){
        orderRepo.delete(order);
    }
    @GetMapping(path = "/orders/regular-bill")
    public OrderBill getTotalRegularBill() {
        var listOrder = this.orderRepo.findAll();
        OrderBill bills = new RegularBill(this.clerk);
        bills.setOrderList(listOrder);
        return bills;
    }
    @GetMapping(path = "/orders/discounted-bill")
    public OrderBill getTotalDiscountedBill() {
        var listOrder = this.orderRepo.findAll();
        OrderBill bills = new DiscountedBill(this.clerk);
        bills.setOrderList(listOrder);
        return bills;
    }
}
```

Application class –

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.company.ws"})
public class OrderBillingWsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OrderBillingWsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I did try all the possible annotations added in my Spring Boot app but still gives me an error.
There are also previous threads with similar description as to my problem but the thread/s doesn't help at all or quite confusing to follow because there are classes that doesn't exist on mine on where would I put the suggested "code". Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very good question since it brings us this end `/` problem.

In a nutshell, `http://localhost:4200` and `http://localhost:4200/` are completely different, even though it pulls up the same page, or the same resource.

Your browser is complaining:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8090/api/orders' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The frontend javascript is of `origin 'http://localhost:4200'`.

However, in your backend application, you configured `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200/")`.

Change it to `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")` or simply `@CrossOrigin`.

Answer (score 1):

According this message "This is what my console says upon running my Angular app (localhost:4200)", this is a CORS issue. You must configure, in your Springboot application, the CorsFilter, like this:

```
@Bean 
public CorsFilter corsFilter() { 
final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source =     new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();     
final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
config.setAllowCredentials(true);
config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
config.addAllowedHeader("*");
config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
config.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config); return new CorsFilter(source);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I am quite confused on where would I put this? Is it on my Application class?

Comment: I actually tried to put this on Application class but I still get the same error by the way.

Comment: You can put it in your Application class or in any other class with @Configuration annotation. But I've seen justthink detected the issue. If you prefer, you can take off the cors configuration from your Controller and make one general cors filter, like I showed. Just put one more line **config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));** that I forgot.